# Unexpected Termination In SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am running a package from SQL Server and it is getting failed and show only `Unexpected Termination`.

When I have gone to Event Viewer I found below error:

> The SSIS Execution Process could not write to the IS catalog: DB_NAME
>   :SSISDB   Error details: Cannot find the symmetric key
>   'MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_28', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.;   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection,

I have gone through below links but unable to find solution

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45d13481-9890-4fa3-b7ac-c893bfd3eea9/unexpected-termination-ssis-package-issue-with-ssis-packages-after-upgrading-to-sql-server-2014?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

http://www.sqlideas.com/2015/05/cannot-find-symmetric-key-x-because-it.html

I found some matching keys i.e

```
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_12,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_13,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_15,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_21,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_22,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_23,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_6,
MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_7
```

But `MS_Enckey_Proj_Param_28` is missing in `sys.symmetric_keys`.

Please give me some Solution.

Comment: ...create the missing key...

Comment: @Paolo are you sure Because it is on production. Please suggest.. :)

Comment: you can't simply create that key out of nowere, you should have proper script to create the key exactly as needed by the code. also such keys are used to encrypt so if you don't create it correctly is useless. and nobody on SO can know which one is the right key for your system... do you happen to have a backup and/or documentation to recover the key from?